# Hue installation issue

Tags: django, hadoop, django-models, hue, python-huey

I am new to bigdata technologies/hadoop ecosystem.

As part of one of my assignment I am trying to install and run Hue on my single node hadoop cluster [apache distribution hadoop2.6.0].

I have installed hue as per the instructions provided by many websites:

1. Downloaded latest hue tar file
2. Unzipped it at one location
3. Ran `sudo make install`
4. It installed hue in /usr/local/hue directory
5. Updated hue.ini file with required details of my cluster.
6. When I am trying to access the newly installed hue through web UI using ':8888', it is showing me following error page:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/wsgiserver.py", line
> ```
>
> 1198, in communicate
>           req.respond()
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/wsgiserver.py", line 568,
>   in respond
>           self._respond()
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/wsgiserver.py", line 580,
>   in _respond
>           response = self.wsgi_app(self.environ, self.start_response)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 206, in **call**
>           response = self.get_response(request)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 194, in get_response
>           response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 236, in handle_uncaught_exception
>           return callback(request, **param_dict)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/views.py", line 304, in serve_500_error
>           return render("500.mako", request, {'traceback': traceback.extract_tb(exc_info[2])})
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line
>   225, in render
>           **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line
>   146, in _render_to_response
>           return django_mako.render_to_response(template, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line
>   125, in render_to_response
>           return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, data_dictionary), **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line
>   114, in render_to_string_normal
>           result = template.render(**data_dict)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py",
>   line 443, in render
>           return runtime.*render(self, self.callable*, args, data)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py",
>   line 786, in _render
>           **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py",
>   line 818, in _render_context
>           _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py",
>   line 844, in _exec_template
>           callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/tmp/tmpjqe8jG/desktop/500.mako.py", line 103, in render_body
>           **M_writer(unicode( commonfooter(messages) ))
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/views.py", line 388, in commonfooter
>           hue_settings = Settings.get_settings()
>         File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 59, in get_settings
>           settings, created = Settings.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/manager.py",
>   line 154, in get_or_create
>           return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 391, in get_or_create
>           six.reraise(*exc_info)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 383, in get_or_create
>           obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 545, in save
>           force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 573, in save_base
>           updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 654, in _save_table
>           result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 687, in _do_insert
>           using=using, raw=raw)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/manager.py",
>   line 232, in _insert
>           return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 1514, in insert_query
>           return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 903, in execute_sql
>           cursor.execute(sql, params)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
>           return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 99, in __exit**
>           six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
>           return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>         File "/usr/local/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 452, in execute
>           return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>       OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

Not sure what does it mean, please help me in resolving this issue

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it :-)

I was facing this issue because of the hue directory ownership.

I changed the owner of my /usr/local/hue folder :

```
$ sudo chown -R hue:hue /usr/local/hue
```

and then tried accessing the URL, it worked. :-)

//Bhupesh